# Are $(l^1, \|.\|_2)$, $(l^2, \|.\|_3)$ Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $l^1=\{(x_n)_n|\, \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|<\infty\}$ with norm $$\|x\|_p=\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

Is $(l^1, \|.\|_2)$ a Banach space?

Is $(l^2, \|.\|_3)$ a Banach space?

For the first question, I guess the answer is negative. I think the Cauchy sequence $x_n=(1, 1/2,\ldots, 1/n, 0,\ldots, 0,\ldots)$ cuold be a counter-example. But I can't prove it converges to some $x\notin l^1$. I have no idea for the second one.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So the point here is just to find some sequence belonging to $l^3\setminus l^2$? Have you tried $x_n=(1,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{3},\ldots,1/\sqrt{n},0,0,\ldots)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ell^1\subset\ell^2$ is a subspace, you are effectively trying to prove that it is not a *closed* subspace of $(\ell^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$, and you have done all the work already.

> The sequence you propose converges in $(\ell^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ to the sequence $\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, but this sequence is not in $\ell^1$, so the subspace $\ell^1\subset\ell^2$ isn't closed, i.e., since $\ell^2$ is complete, the normed vector space $(\ell^1,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is not a Banach space.